# HTTP通信における、中間の攻撃者による内容の改竄について

Tags: http, security

HTTP通信によって対象ホストから帰ってきた文章が、ローカルと対象ホストの間にある悪意のある中継サーバーによって改竄されてしまったものになっていることはありますか。

これが可能だったとして、そのような話をあまり聞かないのは、(つまり、 HTTPで文章を取得しても、ほとんど大体は改竄されていないのは) なぜでしょうか。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

典型的なMitMとしては、ISPが広告を挿入するという事例が複数あって問題になっています(例[[1]](http://arstechnica.com/uncategorized/2008/06/report-nebuad-ads-inserted-via-man-in-the-middle-attack/),[[2]](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2013/04/how-a-banner-ad-for-hs-ok/))。無料をうたうISPが契約にこっそりそういう条項を入れていたりすることもあるので「攻撃」に分類されるとは限りませんが、倫理的にどうなのよ、という議論はあります。

実際の攻撃に使う場合、重要な情報はhttpsで流れるのがほとんどなので、ただネット上にMitMサーバを置いて不特定多数の被害者を待ち受けるのは有効ではないでしょう。けれども対象を絞った攻撃の1ステップとして使われる事例はあります。例えばマルウェアがLAN内にproxyを作って偽のWindows Updateを注入したり[[3]](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/w32flamer-microsoft-windows-update-man-middle)、ルータの脆弱性を突いてDNS設定を改竄し金融機関へのアクセスを横取りしたり[[4]](http://www.cert.pl//news/8019/langswitch_lang/en)等。

Comment: ISPでの実施例と言えば、データ量を減らすため画像を再圧縮するという、いわゆる「通信の最適化」が昨年話題になりましたね: [“通信の最適化”は正当業務行為とみなすべきか？ - 週刊アスキー](http://weekly.ascii.jp/elem/000/000/358/358135/)。

Answer (score 5):

あくまで推測ですが、**「技術的には可能だが、攻撃者にとってコストや労力に見合った対価が得られない」** というのが、あまり改竄事例が見つからない要因なのではないでしょうか。

不特定多数のHTTP通信を中継・傍受するためのサーバとなると、ISPやIXクラスのものが必要になります。自前で用意するにしても他社のをクラックするにしても高コストなのは明らかです。

また、改竄用の中継サーバを用意、あるいはサーバ乗っ取りができたところで、HTTP通信では攻撃者が欲しがるような個人情報は平文では流れてきません。フィッシングサイトを用意して、そこへ誘導するような改竄をすることも一応考えられます。ただ、それならばHTTP通信の改竄なんて面倒なことをしなくとも、最初から大量のスパムメールで誘導させたほうが攻撃者にとって低コストで手っ取り早いでしょう。

他にも理由は色々とありそうですが、ネット犯罪の手口としてHTTP通信の改竄そのものは効果（利益）が期待できないため、結果として事例が少ないのではないかというのが私の考えです。